# Switch all the entries with one another in data frame in R

Tags: r

I have the data frame named `df` and it looks like this

```
       id         diag      rad 

   8810955         A       14.19        
    912519         B       13.47       
    906024         B       12.70        
    843786         A       12.45        
   8911164         B       11.89        
    865128         B       17.95
```

This is just the head of the data frame and there are a lot more values. For a certain percentage of the number of rows want to switch all the `B`'s for `A`'s and all the `A`'s for `B`'s. So I want to "invert" the values in the column `diag`. Is there a way to do this without using for loops? If not, then any solution with for loops is welcome.

I tried using

```
df[sample(nrow(df), round(p*length(df$diag))), ]
```

However this only randomly samples `p` percent of the `df` but it does not switch anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample indices and in this case with `ifelse` you can invert labels:

```
indices <- sample(nrow(df), round(p*length(df$diag)))
df[indices, "diag"] <- ifelse(df$diag[indices] == "A", "B", "A")
```

with `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[sample(.N, round(p*.N)), diag := ifelse(diag == "A", "B", "A")]
```

If you have more than 2 labels you can use `dplyr::case_when` or `data.table::fifelse`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a scalable `data.table` solution using a lookup table with old>>new values. You can replace all values you want, 1, 2 or 100, just add them in `DT.lookup`. Unmatched values will not be replaced, and stay the same.

**sample data**

```
df <- read.table(text="id         diag      rad 
8810955         A       14.19        
912519         B       13.47       
906024         B       12.70        
843786         A       12.45        
8911164         B       11.89        
865128         B       17.95", header = TRUE)
```

**code**

```
library(data.table)
# Create clookup table with old and new values
DT.replace <- data.table(old = c("A","B"), new = c("B","A"))
#    old new
# 1:   A   B
# 2:   B   A

# Perform update join
setDT(df)[DT.replace, diag := i.new, on = .(diag = old)][]
#         id diag   rad
# 1: 8810955    B 14.19
# 2:  912519    A 13.47
# 3:  906024    A 12.70
# 4:  843786    B 12.45
# 5: 8911164    A 11.89
# 6:  865128    A 17.95
```